# Readline in vi mode: how can I access previously executed commands?

Tags: vim, vi, readline

I recently followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826208/making-vim-ubiquitous) post's advice on how to make vi more ubiquitous and I changed my readline mode to vi. Before I did this, I could use the arrow keys to access previously executed commands. This is no longer the case. How can I access previously executed commands from a readline prompt in vi mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readline's `vi` mode starts out in insert mode, and doesn't have the insert mode arrow key bindings found in some versions of `vi`; this means you have to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> first, then the arrow keys or the standard `vi` `h`/`j`/`k`/`l` keys will work.